# how to disable past dates in nz zorro datepicker

Tags: datepicker, ng-zorro-antd

I have this datepicker

```
  <nz-date-picker [(ngModel)]="startDate"
                        ngDefaultControl
                        [nzDisabled]="disabled"
                        name="license-expires"
                        (ngModelChange)="onDateStartChange($event)"
        >
        </nz-date-picker>
```

How to disable past dates (all before today) ?
I tried to use nzDisabled but as I understand it works for whole element.